# Entity Framework 6 Correct a foreign key relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to correct the relationship below.  For some reason, the primary key set on the ChildClass used a composite of the ParentClassId and the ChildClassId when it should have just used the ChildClassId.

```
public partial class ParentClass
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ParentClassId { get; set; }

    public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }

    public string SomeString { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ChildClass> ChildClasses { get; set; }
}

public partial class ChildClass
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("ParentClass"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ParentClassId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ChildClassId { get; set; }

    public virtual ParentClass ParentClass { get; set; }

    public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }

    public string SomeString { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<ParentClass>()
            .HasMany(e => e.ChildClasses)
            .WithRequired(e => e.ParentClass);
}
```

Thus far I have:

```
public partial class ParentClass
{
    public int ParentClassId { get; set; }

    public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }

    public string SomeString { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ChildClass> ChildClasses { get; set; }
}

public partial class ChildClass
{
    public int ChildClassId { get; set; }
    public int ParentClassId { get; set; }

    public virtual ParentClass ParentClass { get; set; }

    public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }

    public string SomeString { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<ParentClass>()
            .HasMany(e => e.ChildClasses)
            .WithRequired(e => e.ParentClass);
}
```

This provides a migration script which just drops and recreates the primary key as expected.

Now, when I load a parent, clear the Child objects and recreate them and then try to save the changes

```
ParentClass p = await db.ParentClasses.Include("ChildClasses").SingleOrDefaultAsync(r => r.ParentClassId == 1).ConfigureAwait(false);
p.ChildClasses.Clear();

ChildClass c = new ChildClass { SomeDate = DateTime.Now, SomeString="some string" };
p.ChildClasses.Add(c);

await db.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); //<< Error on this
```

I get the error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

The tables and associated keys, indexes etc look fine.  The `SaveChanges` line doesn't get as far as the database so somewhere in the model (not visible to me) it seems to be not respecting the updated relationship.

**EDIT:** based on reading around I've also tried iterating through as per below and get the same error.

```
foreach (ChildClass t in p.ChildClasses.ToList()) p.ChildClasses.Remove(t);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What you want when you are doing p.ChildClasses.Clear(); ?

Comment: Does p.ChildClasses.Clear() actually delete the child classes?  The error you get sounds like it’s trying to save the child classes only now without a ParentId.

Comment: Just to clarify, the p.ChildClasses.Clear(); is existing code which was working until I changed the relationship.

Comment: @mattpm, I think, Remove() also does the same as Clear(). Try remove it using context. Like db.Remove(t)

Comment: @DIlshod - cheers.  The EF version I'm using doesn't appear to have a db.Remove(t) method.  However, based on your suggestion I have tried using db.ChildClasses.RemoveRange(p.ChildClasses.ToList()); instead and that has removed the child objects.  Will pick this up again Monday.

Answer (score 3):

`Clear()` method will not delete entities in `ChildClasses` collection. If you think that `ChildClass` can be without `ParentClass` you should make foreign key as nullable

`public int? ParentClassId { get; set; }` then it should work

Comment: Just to clarify, the p.ChildClasses.Clear(); is existing code which was working until I changed the relationship.

Comment: @mattpm, I think, Remove() also does the same as Clear(). Try remove it using context. Like db.Remove(t)